# Qt checkbox/toolbutton with custom/distinct check/unchecked icons

Tags: c++, qt

I need to have a checkbox like control where the checked and unchecked states use a custom graphic. I've looked at all the docs for QToolButton and QCheckBox, along with QIcon but couldn't find any combination that does what I want.

I just want to use one icon (pixmap actually) in the unchecked state, and a different one in the checked state.

This feels like it should be easy, but the solution (short of a custom control) is eluding me.

---

I've tried using a style sheet as well, and `QToolButton:checked` with a `background-image` kind of works but I can't get the layout correct -- it's not positioned/sized as with an icon.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use ::indicator sub-item. the code below works excellent for me...

```
 QCheckBox::indicator {
     width: 18px;
     height: 18px;
 }

  QCheckBox::indicator:checked
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_checked_normal.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_unchecked_normal.png);
  }

  QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_checked_hovered.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_unchecked_hovered.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:checked:pressed
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_checked_pressed.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:pressed
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_unchecked_pressed.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:checked:disabled
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_checked_disabled.png);
  }
  QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:disabled
  {
    image: url(.../Checkbox_unchecked_disabled.png);
  }
```

Comment: are there a way to use Qt Icons instead of importing images in resources?

Comment: For future reference there is also a `:indeterminate` selector which can be used for styling tri-state checkboxes. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states

Answer (score 2):

This must be entered as a StyleSheet. Do this via the Design editor by right click on the check box and selecting "Change stylesheet...".

Answer (score 2):

You may also include and use your icons as resources:

```css
QCheckBox::indicator:checked {image: url(:/circle-green.png);}
QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked {image: url(:/circle-red.png);}
```