# How to place an image on the corner of QGroupBox - StyleSheet

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to know if its possible to display an image instead of text in QGroupBox I want to achieve the following style

[image]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962503/qt-checkbox-toolbutton-with-custom-distinct-check-unchecked-icons

follow this thread

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtdesigner-components.html  Check this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qgroupbox

You could try something like:

```
groupBox->setStyleSheet(
    "QGroupBox::indicator {"
         "width: 13px;"
         "height: 13px;"
    "}"

    "QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked {"
         "image: url(:/images/checkbox_unchecked.png);"
    "}"
 );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: As a note: For this to work the QGroupBox of course has to be set to checkable: `groupBox->setCheckable(true);`. Otherwise the check box area that we are trying to overwrite/change here, will not be visible.